# Creating a dynamic array within a dynamic array in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, dynamic-arrays

I have a form like this one below, which contains steps and each steps contains multiple courses.

```
<div class="si-steps">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-name">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-id">
  <div class="si-courses">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-name">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-id">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="si-course-btn" class="si-course-btn">Add course</button>
</div>
<button type="button" id="si-step-btn" class="si-step-btn">Add step</button>
```

How do i append these properly when i click on the "Add step" and "Add course" buttons ?

i need to add them in this format

```
targetCourse: [{
  step-name: 
  step-id:
  course: [{
    course-name:
    course-id:
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all steps using `querySelectorAll`. Then, iterate through all steps in this collection and gather name, id and courses using `querySelector`.

`Array.prototype.map` will make iteration easier.

```js
var stepElements = document.querySelectorAll('.si-steps');

var result = [].map.call(stepElements, function(stepElement) {
  var courseElements = stepElement.querySelectorAll('.si-courses');
  
  var coursesInfo = [].map.call(courseElements, function(courseElement) {
    return {
      'course-name': courseElement.querySelector("[name='course-name']").value,
      'course-id': courseElement.querySelector("[name='course-id']").value
    };
  });
  
  return {
    'step-name': stepElement.querySelector("[name='step-name']").value,
    'step-id': stepElement.querySelector("[name='step-id']").value,
    'course': coursesInfo
  };
});
  
document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<div class="si-steps">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-name" value="step1">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-id" value="1">
  <div class="si-courses">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-name" value="course1">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-id" id="c1">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="si-course-btn" class="si-course-btn">Add course</button>
</div>

<div class="si-steps">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-name" value="step2">
  <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="step-id" value="2">
  <div class="si-courses">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-name" value="course3">
    <input type="text" class="si-step-input" name="course-id" id="c3">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="si-course-btn" class="si-course-btn">Add course</button>
</div>

<button type="button" id="si-step-btn" class="si-step-btn">Add step</button>

<div>
  <pre id="result">
  </pre>
</div>
```

Note that `Add course` and `Add step` buttons are not implemented. Scroll down the snippet to see result.